# localStorage.setItem() not working on page load

Tags: javascript

I want to load a page and, after the body tag, execute a sort based on localStorage. But myWay (no pun intended) doesn't work. Can you help me?

*I have 3 sort functions, each with one of these lines:*

```
<script>

localStorage.setItem("current_sort", "classSort()");
localStorage.setItem("current_sort", "playerSort()");
localStorage.setItem("current_sort", "ratingSort()");

</script>

<script>

myWay = localStorage.getItem("current_sort");

if (myWay === "") {myWay = "playerSort()";}

</script>
```

How do I load myway?

```
<script>
eval (myway()); //doesn't seem to work.
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you even use the onload event for this?

Comment: HUh. You're right. No reason at all to. But what is the syntax to call a function based on a variable.

Comment: You can not call a function like that it is a string.

Comment: `<body onload = "eval(myWay);">` Use this.

Comment: I ditched the body onload idea as buggy and complicated. I'd just be happy to load the correct function using variable myWay in a script tag.

Answer (score -3):

that is how we execute functions as second parameter:

```
localStorage.setItem("current_sort", function(){classSort()});
localStorage.setItem("current_sort", function(){nameSort()});
localStorage.setItem("current_sort", function(){ratingsort()});
```

Comment: setItem holds a string so setting it to a function will result in something totally different.